# multi task learning using estimates as features

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I have multi task network that has 3 classification heads `[A, B, C]`.
I want use output of head `A` as input to the first dense layers of `B and C`.

Does something special should be done for back propagation as I think that the gradients from `B and C` shouldn't flow back to `A`, as it already was calculated and it should dealt as constant.

Does anyone has code example for something like this ?

Comment: Do you have labels for [A, B, C] or only [B, C]?

Comment: Do you really want to use the output? The layer before probably contains more information.

Comment: @Baschdl, I have the label of A,B,C. In addition I am using the layer before softmax, here it's just for simplicity of the question.

Comment: Then it probably makes sense to prevent the gradients from flowing back. Depending on the problem, you could also use a weighted sum of the gradients where A has a higher weight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try:

```
A_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(5)(x)
A_head= tf.keras.layers.Dense(5)(A_layer)
A_logic = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)(A_head)
A_loss = tf.losses.sigmoid_cross_entropy(A_y,A_logic)

B_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(5)(tf.stop_gradient(A_logic))
B_head= tf.keras.layers.Dense(5)(B_layer)
B_logic = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)(B_head)
B_loss = tf.losses.sigmoid_cross_entropy(B_y,B_logic)

C_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(5)(tf.stop_gradient(A_logic))
C_head= tf.keras.layers.Dense(5)(C_layer)
C_logic = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)(C_head)
C_loss = tf.losses.sigmoid_cross_entropy(C_y,C_logic)

total_loss = A_loss + B_loss + C_loss

train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(total_loss)
```